# Colisão de nomes entre classe e namespace

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, classes, namespace

É errado, má prática ou posso ter problemas com classe igual ao ***namespace***?
Exemplo:

```
namespace Cielo {
    public class Cielo {
        ...
    }
}
```

Tem funcionado, em alguns lugares fica um pouco estranho chamar `Cielo.Cielo.etc`.

Deveria mudar a classe por exemplo para `CieloService` ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Infelizmente a convenção de usar UpperCamelCase também nos nomes dos namespaces pode trazer problemas técnicos ao utilizar o mesmo nome na classe e no namespace (no java a convenção é nomear namespaces com letras minúsculas, evitando a possibilidade de colisão). No seu artigo, Eric Lippert fala que usar o mesmo nome seria uma falha de design na hierarquia, mas ele cita um exemplo bem pobrinho (um namespace *List* com uma classe *List*), só que em aplicativos enterprise é comum querer namespace e classe com nomes iguais; e em C# acabamos tendo que forjar pro namespace um nome não natural :-/

Comment: Este é um padrão de hierarquia válido em sistemas enterprise: *company.domain.context.entity.RootEntity*, *company.domain.context.entity.AggregateEntity1*, *company.domain.context.entity.ValueObject1*. Por exemplo: *dorathoto.erp.estoque.produto.Produto*, *dorathoto.erp.estoque.produto.Categoria*, *dorathoto.erp.estoque.produto.Localização*. Em C# eu tenho que forjar outro nome para o namespace de agregação da entidade Produto. Qual nome seria mais natural que simplesmente "Produto"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Poder, pode, mas não é recomendado. Fica confuso. Há uma recomendação oficial.

Há um [artigo do Eric Lippert](https://web.archive.org/web/20151122031318/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx) (veja as outras partes) sobre isto.

O ideal é nomear as coisas como elas são. A classe **é um** Cielo? Ou ela é um **Serviço** específico da **Cielo**?

Já o *namespace* é da Cielo, certo? Tudo que está lá dentro é deles. Se você não é a Cielo não deveria usar este nome.

Deu para entender como nomear?

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: sim, deixou claro que é preciso renomear..mas ainda sobre os nomes não sei. O Sistema é um webservice da Cielo, possui diversos serviços, WebService, WindowForm, Mas acho que vou seguir em namespace Cielo e classe CieloWebService

Answer (score 4):

Nenhuma das opções.

O *namespace* serve para dar contexto aos componentes que está utilizando. Ele é apenas útil ao desenvolvedor.

Ter nome de uma classe com mesmo nome do *namespace* irá gerar alguma confusão, pois em algumas vezes não será possível usar o *using* normalmente, terá que sempre ser explícito: `var cielo = new Cielo.Cielo();`.

Enfim, questão de gosto. Recomendo que, se der, evite fazer isso, como o exemplo que deu de `CieloService` ou `CieloClient`, sei lá.

Mas, não é errado, e nunca li nada e não vejo como **má prática**.